# Google scripts function to fetch curl data to Google Sheets

Tags: json, curl, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to fetch some data to a google sheet. The code goes like this:

```
function ls() {
var url = "https://api.loanscan.io/v1/interest-rates?tokenFilter=BTC";
var params = {
         "contentType": "application/json",
         "headers":{"x-api-key": "KEY",
                    },

         };

var json = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
var jsondata=json.getContentText();
var page = JSON.parse(jsondata);
Logger.log page
return page;

}
```

The Logger.log gives the correct Data, as you can see in the next link.

[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVtIn.png)

However when I run the function in the google sheet, it returns a blank cell.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: You need to learn to mould the data to a 2d array. Look into importjson script.

Answer (score 0):

You should write the `Logger.log(page);` with parentheses, because sheets is probably hanging on your Logger statement. 
I don't have an API key for that site, but I do get the forbidden error response from the API when using `=ls()` in a cell in sheets.